# What is the best replacement for table to make it responsive

Tags: responsive-design, html-table

I want to make a table, but as it is responsive to some extent we all know that. Do anybody know what will be best replacement for making table without using table tag.

I have provided the basic table html, help me with that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully responsive table

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  
  /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
  #no-more-tables table, 
  #no-more-tables thead, 
  #no-more-tables tbody, 
  #no-more-tables th, 
  #no-more-tables td, 
  #no-more-tables tr { 
    display: block; 
  }
 
  /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
  #no-more-tables thead tr { 
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
  }
 
  #no-more-tables tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
 
  #no-more-tables td { 
    /* Behave  like a "row" */
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%; 
    white-space: normal;
    text-align:left;
  }
 
  #no-more-tables td:before { 
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%; 
    padding-right: 10px; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This worked for me. Reference :- https://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/